# jw token verify invalid socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to authenticate jwt token when using socket.io 
by passing user token from client side to the server side then using jwt verify function, i get the following error :

JsonWebTokenError: invalid token

```
socket.on('addBackorder', (newBackorder, token) => {


    jwt.verify(token, 'secret_key', function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log('decoded: ', decoded);
            backorderControler.addBackorder(io, newBackorder, user_id);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: so maybe your token is invalid?

Comment: @BraveButter the token is being passed from localStorage

Comment: You could print your jwt and try to validate it here (https://jwt.io/) to be sure it is correct.

Comment: i get the payload and Signature Verified

Comment: @BraveButter thank you for the help, I figured it out, i have to remove "Bearer" from the token

Comment: Also. I could decode the token without the secret key, which is strange, any input on that behavior

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399950/decoding-jwt-tokens-without-the-secret